# How to improve print quality when print from browser to Dot Matrix Printer?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, printing

How to improve print quality when print from browser to Dot Matrix Printer Epson LQ-310.
i have tried with almost all suitable font but print quality is still poor.
i understand when i print from browser in my case i'am using google chrome it converts webpage to pdf first before printing.

[image]

here u can see the print quality.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

  <meta charset="UTF-8">

  <title></title>

  <style>
    @media print {
      @page :footer {
        display: none
      }
      @page :header {
        display: none
      }
      thead,
      tfoot {
        display: none !important
      }
      .page-break {
        display: block;
        page-break-before: always;
        size: 210mm 297mm;
        font-size: 24pt;
        font-family: calibri;
      }
      .noprint {
        visibility: hidden;
      }
    }
    
    #invoice-POS {
      font-family: calibri;
      width: 90mm;
    }
    
    #invoice-POS ::selection {
      background: #f31544;
      color: #FFF;
    }
    
    #invoice-POS ::moz-selection {
      background: #f31544;
      color: #FFF;
    }
    
    #invoice-POS h1 {
      font-size: 1.5em;
      color: #222;
    }
    
    #invoice-POS h2 {
      font-size: .9em;
    }
    
    #invoice-POS h3 {
      font-size: 1.2em;
      font-weight: 300;
      line-height: 2em;
    }
    
    #invoice-POS p {
      font-size: .7em;
      color: #666;
      line-height: 1.2em;
    }
    
    #invoice-POS #top,
    #invoice-POS #mid,
    #invoice-POS #bot {
      /* Targets all id with 'col-' */
      border-bottom: 1px solid #EEE;
    }
    
    #invoice-POS #top {
      min-height: 100px;
    }
    
    #invoice-POS #mid {
      min-height: 80px;
    }
    
    #invoice-POS #bot {
      min-height: 50px;
    }
    
    #invoice-POS .info {
      display: block;
      margin-left: 0;
    }
    
    #invoice-POS .title {
      float: right;
    }
    
    #invoice-POS .title p {
      text-align: right;
    }
    
    #invoice-POS table {
      width: 100%;
      border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    
    #invoice-POS .tabletitle {
      font-size: .5em;
      background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    }
    
    #invoice-POS .service {
      border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    #invoice-POS .service1 {
      border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 1em;
    }
    
    #invoice-POS .item {
      width: 18mm;
    }
    
    #invoice-POS .item1 {
      width: 5mm;
    }
    
    #invoice-POS .itemtext {
      font-size: .5em;
    }
    
    #invoice-POS #legalcopy {
      margin-top: 5mm;
    }
    
    td {
      font-weight: bolder;
      font-size: 10pt;
    }
    
    .td1 {
      font-weight: bolder;
      font-size: 14pt;
    }
    
    .td2 {
      font-weight: bolder;
      font-size: 10pt;
    }
  </style>

  <script>
    window.console = window.console || function(t) {};
  </script>



  <script>
    if (document.location.search.match(/type=embed/gi)) {
      window.parent.postMessage("resize", "*");
    }
  </script>


</head>

<body translate="no">


  <div id="invoice-POS">

    <center>



      <div class="td1">
        Techs Inc<br>


      </div>

      <div class="td2">

        street city</br>
        Mysore

      </div>
    </center>
    <!--End Invoice Mid-->

    <div id="bot">

      <div id="table">
        <table>
          <tr class="service">

            <th class="item1"> Sl NO </th>
            <th class=""> Item Name </th>

            <th class="item"> Qty </th>
            <th class="item"> Price </th>

            <th class="item"> Amount </th>
          </tr>

          <tr class="service">
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Product No2</td>

            <td>1</td>
            <td>
              500.00 </td>

            <td>
              500.00 </td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="service">
            <td>2</td>
            <td>Product 1</td>

            <td>1</td>
            <td>
              500.00 </td>

            <td>
              500.00 </td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="service">
            <td>3</td>
            <td>Product 1</td>

            <td>1</td>
            <td>
              500.00 </td>

            <td>
              500.00 </td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="service">
            <td>4</td>
            <td>Product 1</td>

            <td>1</td>
            <td>
              500.00 </td>

            <td>
              500.00 </td>
          </tr>

          <tr class="service">
            <td colspan="2" style=" text-align:left;font-size: 12px;">Total Qty: 4</td>
            <td colspan="2" style=" text-align:right;">Total: &nbsp;</td>
            <td colspan="2">
              2500.00 </td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="">
            <td colspan="2" style=" text-align:right;"></td>

          </tr>
          <tr class="">
            <td colspan="2" style=" text-align:right;"></td>

          </tr>



        </table>
      </div>
      <!--End Table-->


    </div>
    <!--End InvoiceBot-->
  </div>
  <!--End Invoice-->
  <button class="noprint" onclick="window.print()">Click Here to Print</button>

  <script>
    function PrintElem() {
      Popup($html);
    }

    function Popup(data) {
      var myWindow = window.open('', 'Receipt', 'height=400,width=600');
      myWindow.document.write('<html><head><title>Receipt</title>');
      /*optional stylesheet*/ //myWindow.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" type="text/css" />');
      myWindow.document.write('<style type="text/css"> *, html {margin:0;padding:0;} </style>');
      myWindow.document.write('</head><body>');
      myWindow.document.write(data);
      myWindow.document.write('</body></html>');
      myWindow.document.close(); // necessary for IE >= 10

      myWindow.onload = function() { // necessary if the div contain images

        myWindow.focus(); // necessary for IE >= 10
        myWindow.print();
        myWindow.close();
      };
    }
  </script>



</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I'm afraid there's nothing you can do with JS or Print settings to improve the print.

Comment: From that printout, it looks like the printer is faulty or loaded with paper it can't correctly handle.

Comment: You may be able to improve it by prioritizing quality in the printer properties.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove all spaces in your HTML and indentation.
Test juste a grid to find something how' s create gap
Try with juste texte. Debug with cancellation.
Try to do your grid with other html tag or css like flexbox, grid ...
Matrix printer is very specific device.